# How to replace startActivityForResult with Activity Result APIs?

Tags: android, android-activity, androidx, onactivityresult

I have a main activity which serves as an entry point to call different activities, depending on condition. Among others, I use Firebase Auth to manage user sign in:

```
startActivityForResult(
            AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build(),
            RC_SIGN_IN)
```

I overwrite `onActivityResult()` to distinguish the returned intent/data, for example:

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {

        REQUEST_CODE_1 -> {
          // update UI and stuff
        }

        RC_SIGN_IN -> {
          // check Firebase log in
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

With the Activity Result APIs which is strongly recommended by the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result), I get that I should make `prepareCall()` before `ActivityResultLauncher` and to make sure the activity is in created state when I launch, but I still don't understand how to handle multiple activity results gracefully (at least, in one place) like in `onActivityResult()`.

Looking at [this article](https://adambennett.dev/2020/03/introducing-the-activity-result-apis/), it seems I need to implement *multiple* child inner classes of `ActivityResultContract` type (therefore multiple `prepareCall()`'s?), because they are suppose to be different *contracts*, am I correct? Can someone please show me some skeleton example that mirrors the above `onActivityResult()` logic?

Answer (score 75):

You can call as many Activities for result as you wish and have separate callback for each:

```
val startForResult = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result: ActivityResult ->
    if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //  you will get result here in result.data
    }
}

startForResult.launch(Intent(activity, CameraCaptureActivity::class.java))
```

You just need to specify Activity class - `CameraCaptureActivity::class.java`

**Update (as [rafael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8839059/rafael-tavares) mentioned):**

> The prepareCall() method has been renamed to
> registerForActivityResult() in Activity 1.2.0-alpha04 and Fragment
> 1.3.0-alpha04. And it should be startForResult.launch(...) in the last line

Comment: What about passing `'android.content.Intent intent, int requestCode'` as parameters?

Comment: But, in order to send back the result from Activity2, is the same as always?: setResult(Bundle)???

Comment: it returns result.data as null

Answer (score 51):

From now, `startActivityForResult()` has been deprecated so use new method instead of that.

**Example**

```
public void openActivityForResult() {
    
 //Instead of startActivityForResult use this one
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class);
        someActivityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
    }


//Instead of onActivityResult() method use this one

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // Here, no request code
                        Intent data = result.getData();
                        doSomeOperations();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Try this code with google signin onActivityForResult with no luck , any suggestions?

Comment: this code worked for me; had to translate to kotlin though. thanks

Comment: Thank you for not using "var" and lambdas :)

Comment: @paulsm4 You're welcome! I wrote without it because its easy to understand.

Comment: i forgot what function for make the someActivityResultLauncher have result ok , what trigger on activity to set result ok ?

Comment: what about multiple intents, please see this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72729119/android-how-to-differentiate-between-multiple-intents-when-using-activityresult

Comment: Hi, @PembaTamang please check your post. I answered that

Answer (score 23):

*First, don’t forget to add this to your Gradle dependency*

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha05'
```

*Second, create your result contract by extending an abstract class called `ActivityResultContract<I, O>`. I mean the type of input and O means the type of output. And then you only need to override 2 methods*

```
class PostActivityContract : ActivityResultContract<Int, String?>() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Int): Intent {
        return Intent(context, PostActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(PostActivity.ID, postId)
        }
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): String? {
        val data = intent?.getStringExtra(PostActivity.TITLE)
        return if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) data
        else null
    }
}
```

*And finally, the last step is registering the contract to `Activity`. You need to pass your custom contract and callback into `registerForActivityResult`.*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
      
        start_activity_contract.setOnClickListener {
            openPostActivityCustom.launch(1)
        }
    }
  
    // Custom activity result contract
    private val openPostActivityCustom =
        registerForActivityResult(PostActivityContract()) { result ->
            // parseResult will return this as string?                                              
            if (result != null) toast("Result : $result")
            else toast("No Result")
        }
}
```

For More info check this [Post](https://proandroiddev.com/is-onactivityresult-deprecated-in-activity-results-api-lets-deep-dive-into-it-302d5cf6edd)

Comment: Was looking for the dependencies, Thanks for adding this. Get a upvote :)

Comment: Good to hear that it helped you :)

Comment: A good approach to specify the requesting `Intent`! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In this case, what was returned by AuthUI was already an Intent, so, we use it like in the example below.

```
private val startForResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            when(result.resultCode){
                RESULT_OK -> {
                    val intent = result.data
                    // Handle the Intent...
                    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
                }
                RESULT_CANCELED -> {

                } else -> {
            } }
        }
```

start the activity from anywhere (for example on button click) using:

```
 AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setAvailableProviders(providers)
            .build().apply {
                startForResult.launch(this)
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start an activity from a fragment and return result to the fragment, do this.

In fragment:

```
private lateinit var activityResult: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

activityResult = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
    if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val data = result.data
        doSomeOperations(data)
    }
}

SomeActivity.showScreen(activityResult, requireContext())
```

In activity:

```
// activity?.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK) doesn't change.

companion object {

    fun showScreen(activityResult: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>, context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent(context, SomeActivity::class.java)
        activityResult.launch(intent)
    }
}
```

Comment: what is SomeActivity.showScreen(activityResult, requireContext()) i mean what is showScreen ??? can you more describe ?

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo, `fun showScreen(activityResult: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>, context: Context)` in the 2nd part of the answer. You can open an activity `SomeActivity` from a fragment, do some actions and return a result from that activity to the fragment.

Comment: @YogiArifWidodo, forgot to say that in Activity we should return a result with `setResult(RESULT_OK, data)` if I remember.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build());

            ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.v("LOGIN OK", "OK Result for Login");
                }
            });
            
            launcher.launch(AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                    .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                    .build());
```

See this For More Details :
https://githubmemory.com/repo/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues?cursor=Y3Vyc29yOnYyOpK5MjAyMS0wMy0wNVQyMjoxNzozMyswODowMM4xEAQZ&pagination=next&page=2

Answer (score 1):

Use This for Firebase AuthUI;

```
final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> launcher = registerForActivityResult(
            new FirebaseAuthUIActivityResultContract(), this::onSignInResult);

    binding.loginSignup.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> provider = Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build());
        Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                .setAlwaysShowSignInMethodScreen(true)
                .setAvailableProviders(provider)
                .build();
        launcher.launch(intent);
    });


private void onSignInResult(FirebaseAuthUIAuthenticationResult result) {

    if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            if (user.getMetadata() != null) {
                if (user.getMetadata().getCreationTimestamp() != user.getMetadata().getLastSignInTimestamp()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                startMainActivity();
            }
        }
    } else {
        IdpResponse response = result.getIdpResponse();
        if (response == null)
            Toast.makeText(this, "Canceled By You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ActivityResult" + response.getError());
    }
}

private void startMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Like This.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openSomeActivityForResult() {
    someActivityResultLauncher.launch(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .setAvailableProviders(providers)
                .build());
}

// You can do the assignment inside onAttach or onCreate, i.e, before the activity is displayed
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    // There are no request codes
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    doSomeOperations();
                }
                else if(result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // code for cancelled result here
                }
            }
        });
```